# Positivity of certain Fourier transform

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Is the Fourier transform of the function
$$ f(\xi) = e^{-t|\xi|^{2m}}$$
positive for $t>0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$?

Comment: See also this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228462/is-the-fourier-transform-of-e-xn-positive. Note that the linked question is different to the one above, but the top-voted answer to the linked question does not answer the linked question, but instead the question asked above!

Comment: I love it when simple questions like this one generate such wonderful answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it is positive for $m=1$, but not for $m=2$, see this Mathematica output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have done this myself. Thought too abstractly about it -.-

Answer (score 25):

A simple argument that the Fourier transform cannot be nonnegative for any $m>1$, integer or not, is given in my 1991 paper with Odlyzko and Rush:

> Noam D. Elkies, Andrew M. Odlyzko, and Jason A. Rush: [On the packing densities of superballs and other bodies](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002108941), *Invent. Math.* **105** (1991), 613-639.

The Fourier transform $f$ of a nonnegative even function must satisfy
$4f(\xi) \leq 3 f(0) + f(2\xi)$ for all $\xi$.  This fails for any $m>1$ once $\xi$ is close enough to (but not equal) zero.

**Postscripts:**

0) The inequality $4f(\xi) \leq 3 f(0) + f(2\xi)$ holds because
the difference is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\eta) \, w(\eta) \, d\eta$
with $w(\eta) \geq 0$ for all $\eta$ because
$3 - 4\cos \theta + \cos 2\theta = 8 \sin^4 (\theta/2) \geq 0$.

1) The nonnegativity of $3 - 4\cos \theta + \cos 2\theta$
is also a key ingredient in the proof of thenonvanishing of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ on the edge
$s = 1+it$ of the critical strip, and thus of the Prime Number Theorem.
See the last exercise of
[this chapter](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M229.15/free.pdf)
my notes on analytic number theory.

2) **Sergei** noted that it is also known that for $0 < m \leq 1$
the Fourier transform *is* positive.  As I wrote earlier this year
[on Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846072),
the same paper with Odlyzko and Rush also proves that fact as follows, 
crediting the argument to B.F. Logan (see Lemma 5 on page 626).
We first prove this for $m=1$, then reduce $0<m<1$ to this case.
For $m=1$, the function $\exp(-t|\xi|^{2m})$ is a Gaussian, 
and thus so is its Fourier transform; Gaussians are positive everywhere,
so the case $m=1$ is done.  For $0<m<1$, the function
$\exp(-t|\xi|^{2m})$ is a nonnegative mixture of Gaussians $\exp(-c\xi^2)$ by
[Bernstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions).
Therefore the Fourier transform is also a nonnegative mixture of Gaussians,
so again positive everywhere.  **QED**

Answer (score 16):

I think the result goes back to Polya, see ["Some theorems on stable processes"](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-095-02/S0002-9947-1960-0119247-6/) by Blumenthal and Getoor. Another reference is Paul Lévy "Sur une application de la dérivée d’ordre non entier au calcul des probabilités" page 1118 of [CRAS 1923](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k31295.r=comptes%20rendus%20academie%20des%20sciences%201923?rk=42918;4).

It might be good to also give the gist of Levy's very simple argument: if the Fourier transform was positive then the exponent would be the log-moment generating function of a random variable $X$. But if $m>1$, the second derivative at the origin vanishes and thus also the variance of $X$. The positive function would be a delta function which is a contradiction.

Comment: Due to information in 2013 V.P.Zastavny thesis a problem was first in more general form formulated in Schoenberg,1938,Tran.AMS 44. Interesting generalizations are in Zastavnyi V. P. Positive definite functions depending on the norm / V. P.
Zastavnyi // Russian J. Math. Physics. – 1993. – Vol. 1,ð4. – P. 511–
522. and Koldobskii : http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=255&option_lang=eng

Comment: @Sergei: thanks for pointing out the work of Zastavnyi. However, the latter seems to consider the (more difficult) case where the norm involved is $L^p$ with $p>2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 8):

This is a well-known problem, solved recently in dissertation of Zastavny based on some inequalities for p.d.f.
More: it is a Schonberg problem, positive for $0<m\leq1$, not positive otherwise.